# Doma Genで 生成したDaoクラスファイルのselectAllがありません

Tags: java, seaser2

doma-genの定義ファイルで、この[サイト](http://doma.seasar.org/extension/doma_gen_gen_task.html)いうように、独自テンプレートディレクトリで、selectAll.sql.ftiを作成すれば、生成したリーソースディレクトリで、selectAll.sqlファイルを作成できますが、生成したのDAOファイルで、selectAllメソッドを追加されていません。DomaConfigで、何か設定が必要でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

selectAllメソッドが定義されたDAOを生成したい場合は、DAO用のテンプレートファイルを用意する必要があります。配布ファイルに含まれているdao.ftlを修正してselectAllメソッドの定義を加えてください。新しいDAO用のテンプレートファイルの名前はそのままdao.ftlとし独自テンプレートディレクトリに配置してください。

下記のドキュメントを参照ください。
[http://doma.seasar.org/extension/doma_gen_gen_task.html#独自のテンプレートファイルを使用する](http://doma.seasar.org/extension/doma_gen_gen_task.html#%E7%8B%AC%E8%87%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)